# Is NDK an alternative to reduce reverse engineering?

Tags: android, android-ndk, proguard, reverse-engineering

I have given up trying to get Proguard to work on either Eclipse or Android Studio.  The docs are arcane and whatever I try, the Proguard obfuscated apk blows.  Also questions regarding Proguard don't get much attention on this forum.

Standard Android apk files are designed to almost invite reverse engineering and I'm looking for some ways to protect my code.  Not all my code just some methods.

Before I started writing Android apps, I wrote apps in C and in C# and I'm familiar with both of those languages and actually prefer either of them to Java so I've recently been reading about the NDK.

Of course the NDK is about  speed but I'm wondering if it also would help protect my code against reverse engineering and inspection from hackers.  I understand that it is "compiled" code so I imagine that the source code would not be visible.

Am I barking up the right tree?

Thanks,

Dean

Comment: Having to reverse-engineer from disassembled machine code isn't going to stop a motivated person / group. It might discourage a novice without sufficient interest to spend the necessary time analyzing the disassembly.

Comment: Note that commercial code obfuscators exist (both for Java code and native code), that go quite far beyond the relatively simple obfuscation that ProGuard does. I'm not at liberty to name any such tools that I may or may not have experience with; I'm just saying that ProGuard isn't the only alternative if this is something that you find important.

Comment: *"the Proguard obfuscated apk blows"* - what does that mean? would help to know what is lacking with proguard obfuscation that you'd like to get out of other obfuscation techniques.

Comment: Sam: "blows" means "Unfortunately, [myappname] has stopped" at which point I would have an obfuscated stack trace to deal with.  See some of my recent prior posts if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what kind of protection you are looking for. If that is a revolutionary algorithm that will allow you do some very popular task much much faster than it takes today, then your code will be reverse engineered, no matter how you obfuscate it; you need patent protection. If you want to hide some unfriendly behavior (like spying on your users), it will be discovered. So don't do it. If you want to protect some protocol of client-server communication, it may be subject to easy attack elsewhere.

But in some cases going C++ does really help; it may be easier to distribute a monolithic shared library "black box" than to deal with Java API. I don't think obfuscation can work on code that you sell as library.

When we were selling a huge communication SDK, we followed this approach, and all our Java code was simply open to customers (part was intended to be changed/customized, but some classes carried a warning in the header *"Please don't modify this class, there is very high chance that the product will not work properly if you mess with it"*.

Comment: can you suggest any tools to check SDK/NDK via reverse engineering, I tried using apktool but was not able to view it.

Comment: @Rick I don't understand what kind of 'check' you have in mind.

Comment: Actually My friend has stored DB encryption password in NDK, I am trying to do reverse engineering and try to obtain that password.I have tried using apktool and renaming apk to zip etc but no success yet

Answer (score 4):

Native C code is harder to decompile but it can be decompiled easily using the right tools.

Especially if you only develop small parts in C and then communicate with it using JNI which is a clear interface, anybody who decompiles your app can also use it. Who needs to know how your code works if you can simply execute it?

Conclusion: native code can be harder to decompile. But usually the only difference is that you need different tools and you need more knowledge & practice to decompile. Also modifying something is usually more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Just implementing some methods in NDK alone will not likely help a lot. However, the resistance to reverse engineering can be improved if you also apply obfuscation and even run-time protection techniques to your NDK code. A simply web search gives [a list of free tools](https://sites.google.com/site/opensourceconstriubtions/ettl-martin-1/tutorials/what-tools-are-available-to-automatically-obfuscate-c-c-code). You could also work with commercial solution providers like Arxan.  In addition, the level of obfuscation can generally be improved if you put more logic of your app in native code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes if you use the NDK you can make it very difficult to reverse engineer your code and it is unlikely anybody would try.

Comment: can you ellaborate on why? otherwise this seems like a comment.

Comment: _"it is unlikely anybody would try"_. If it's a valuable enough target to attack, it's not at all unlikely that someone would attempt to do so.

Comment: The NDK will create compiled code, and thus can be read as a file, and the "intruder" is likely to have a table of commands ready, to recreate the operations used. It is going to make it harder, but will not obfuscate your code, only remove the "name" of the variables for symbol pointers... But, the obfuscation in Java will still not be enough. As far as I have seen, the only way to protect a code, is have it run "Server Side", as in have the operations be done outside of the JVM...